# Does "indistinctly" work as meaning "interchangeably"?

Tags: meaning

There is a fairly sticky Meta question at Spanish Language SE, for which part of the answer uses the word "indistinctly" in the sense of "interchangeably."  It looks wrong to my eye.  However, the dictionary definition seems to indicate that it's okay.

> A is used indistinctly with B, though the latter is preferred.

What do the experts say?

Link to post: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2692/9385

Comment: Which dictionary are you using? The first one I checked gives only one meaning for "indistinct", namely "not clear or sharply defined" (which matches what I always thought it meant).

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question?  My guess without context would be that the author meant to use "indistinguishably" and found something wrong with it, and went with a "wrong" word.

Comment: @xanne - Okay, added.  Hope that helps.

Comment: DRAE: Diccionario de la RAE. Used indistinctly with "DLE", though the latter is preferred.  "Indiscriminately" may be what the writer meant.

Comment: You're asking users  to leave the site to visit the Spanish page, and then leave it again in order to check the dictionary's definition because .... why? Why can't you include an extract and the word's definition in your question?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I've added an example sentence.

Answer (score 2):

*OED* provides an *obsolete* definition of **indistinctly** that has some attested uses where the word functions much like "interchangeably."

> †1. In such a way as not to distinguish or make a difference between things, persons, or cases; without distinction; indifferently, indiscriminately.

The most recent attested use:

> After the year of Probation, when this Habit is common and **indistinctly** given to Novices and Persons profess'd.

- 1726   J. Ayliffe *Parergon Juris Canonici Anglicani* 370

However, besides using a definition marked obsolete, what makes this construction appear strange to me is the preposition "with."

We know that **interchangeably** works with "with."

> A is used **interchangeably** *with* B.

And the dictionary definition of "indistinctly" seems to sanction a construction such as:

> A and B are used **indistinctly**.

But I find *indistinctly* to be awkward preceding "with," perhaps because concepts are often described as being **distinct from** each other not **distinct with** them.

> **Distinguish** A **from** B.
>
> **Interchange** A **with** B.
>
> **Alternate** A **with** B.
>
> ? A is used **indistinctly** *with* B

My conclusion is that **indistinctly** and **interchangeably** cannot be used **indistinctly** or **interchangeably** in *all* cases and usually one makes more sense than the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I added an example sentence to the question.